# Matlab making a simple plot

Tags: matlab

I have an array a
I checked its status and got

```
>>size(a)
354 2
>>class(a)
double
```

I tried to do

```
>>plot(a)
```

but i got two graphs and not one

Comment: What do you want to plot exactly? Try `imagesc(a)` maybe?

Comment: you need either `plot( a(:,1), a(:,2))` or `plot( a(:,2), a(:,1))` depending on how you want to distribute the data on the axes.

Answer (score 3):

plot(a) creates a 2-D line plot of the data in a versus the index of each value.

Since there is size of 354,2, it creates 2 plots.. Look at this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzptin

In the same example, there was a statement:

```
plot(X,Y) creates a 2-D line plot of the data in Y versus the corresponding values in X.
```

So you need to find x vector which forms the x axis and Y in your case will be a or depending on what is in a. If it contains both x and y, then you plot(a(:,1),a(:,2)).